# android-safetynet attestation replacement in webauthn after deprecation

Tags: authentication, android-security, google-identity, webauthn, fido

android-safetynet attestation format is provided in webauthn in both browser API or FIDO2 Api for Android. Since safetynet API will be deprecated soon, what will be the replacement of safetynet attestation?

android-key attestation format is mentioned in the webauthn specification document and is supported using Android keystore but it's not clear if it will be used for webauthn as a replacement of android-safetynet.

Can you please provide clarity for this topic?

Comment: Passkeys are not currently attested using traditional attestation formats. Which specific credential types are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has not yet made an announcement about any replacement for SafetyNet attestation for non-discoverable credentials on Android.